# How do i set a main page in Subdirectory?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a subdirectory in my website which goes by `www.example.com/forum/` i made a `.htaccess` file there and wrote the following code;

```
#Alternate default index pages
DirectoryIndex portal.php
```

but it doesn't really work, what am i doing wrong or what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to know the problem and solved it,
figured out that I haven't added `AllowOverride All` to my subfolder directory.

Added the following code in `apache2.conf` and the `.htaccess` is working now fine.

```
<Directory /var/www/html/forum/>
AllowOverride all
Require all granted
</Directory>
```